# YouTube Data API video upload cost

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it always true that the cost of a video upload is 1600?

I can see on [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) that the `videos` / `insert` mutation costs 1600, but I was wondering if this could take more if I upload a very large video?

Comment: AFAIK YouTube quota cost is always constant. May I know what order of magnitude size are you thinking of by *a very large video* ?

Comment: Let's say 10 hours of a 4K video. I guess this would be also 1600?

Answer (score 0):

yes videos insert costs 1600 quota units.  The size, length or quality of the video does not matter.  This is stated at the top of the [Quota cost page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

> **The table below shows the quota cost for calling each API method.** All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.

All costs are incurred per call to the method in question.